# Unit of dimensions of image using VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

The code written below is used to set the position and size of in image in powerpoint using vba-excel macro:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 400
    .Left = 50
    .Top = 50
End With
```

What are the units in which these dimensions are given? how many inches does 400 point equals?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The units are **points**. There are exactly 72 points in an inch.

(So 400 points equates to 5<sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>9</sub>  inches)

Comment: i want an image whose ht is 2.18" and width is 4.64" .

Comment: No, you need 2.18 * 72 and 4.62 * 72. It's possible that your shape is locking its aspect ratio. Check some other properties.

Comment: i did that, but bo matter what i do..the ht remains 2.66" even though i put 2.18" or any other dimension

Comment: SO what could be the problem?

Comment: Presumably you're now using `.Height = 157` and `.Width = 333`?

Comment: Yes, but when i check the dimensions of the image after its getting pasted, the width comes out to be correct but the height is 2.66".

Comment: This is almost certainly due to the fact that the shape has its aspect ratio locked. There will be a property like "lockAspectRatio" that you'll need to set to false